# Is there a way to have discord bots write to a file when hosted on heroku?

Tags: heroku, bots

My Discord bot has a level system that requires it to write to a JSON file.

I am hosting it on Heroku and it's currently not updating the file. I know Heroku cannot save data, so is there a way I can code it to write to the file on my computer?

I followed Tech With Tim's tutorial on how to host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku filesystem is ephemeral so every change is lost after the redeployment/restart of the Dyno.

Your options are to use a database or an external file storage, which is probably what you want as you need to save a JSON file.

Heroku cannot access your computer over the network (unless you tunnel the requests using ngrok, that is possible but not very practical).
You can save the file to a remote storage service (like Amazon S3) or integrate with some other cloud service (Google docs using Google Drive API).

Comment: That’s good! I’ll try using Amazon S3. Is there any extra code I need to add?

Comment: You  can use a Java/Python API to send the file to Amazon (you will find plenty of examples), Heroku has a variety of addon (https://elements.heroku.com/addons/) integrate external services but I dont if they are free

Comment: So all I need to do is send the file to Amazon, and then add some code to access the file there?

Comment: You need some code to send the file to Amazon (to save it whenever you need - every 10 min? after a certain event?). From Amazon S3 you can get it using other code (from another application) or also the S3 User Interface you just want to browse and get to the file